# MultipartFile - how to detect real path of file on user's machine

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm facing the following problem: I use MultipartFile to sumbit an image with some other information like email etc.

Consider a situation when we have two fields: input = text with email and input with file (input type = file). On the server side I have validation that checks email. And now imagine that user has entered invalid email, has chosen a file that he wants to upload and has submited a form. After that server recognizes that email is invalid and returns page where email input is fulfilled with value that user previously entered (pretty ease to support using DTOs) but file input is empty (DTO contains MultipartFile field that stores file previously uploaded by user). I was thinking that its a bad practice to send path to file along with file because this is not secure and because of that MultipartFile probably doesn't store file path. Can you please give a hint how to handle this situation? Thank you!

Comment: An example would help us understand.....

Comment: Consider a situation when we have two fields: input = text with email and input with file (input type = file). On the server side I have validation that checks email. And now imagine that user has entered invalid email, has chosen a file that he wants to upload and has submited a form. After that server recognizes that email is invalid and returns page where email input is fulfilled with value that user previously entered (pretty ease to support using dtos) but file input is empty.

Comment: Please don't clarify as comment but extend your initial question that way all information is grouped together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full path of an uploaded file has no meaning at the server side and it might be considered sensitive data (as full path might include user name etc.).

Basic file uploaders and the HTML `<input>` tag with `type=file` in a form don't send the full path and neither should you.

**Edit (in response to your edit):**

You can check other fields of your form at client side (JavaScript) before you submit your form. If anything is invalid, alert the user and don't submit the form.

Or you can submit the form data with an AJAX call and do the check/validation at server side.